# Properties of Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For each part of this problem, give sets A,B, and C, with C ⊂ A, and a function f : A → B satisfying the given conditions. Or, if no such function exists, prove that none exists. (There is no need to get fancy here. In each case where such an f exists, an example can be constructed in which each of the sets A,B,C has at most two elements.)

a) f is surjective and the restriction f|C is surjective.

b) f is surjective but f|C is not surjective.

c) f is injective and f|C is injective.

d) f is injective and f|C is not injective.

I cannot find examples of these sets. If anyone has an idea, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(a): $A=\{0,1\}$, $C=\{0\} \subset A$ and $B=\{0\}$. Then the function $f:A \rightarrow B$ with $f(0)=f(1)=0$ satisfies the given conditions.

Similarly simple examples work for the other parts.

Comment: Hint: Examples exist for (b) and (c), but not (d).

Comment: These are so hard, any way you could give me any more help?

Comment: For (b), you can try the sets $A=\{0,1\}$, $C=\{0\} \subset A$, and $B=\{0,1\}$. Can you think of a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ which is surjective (i.e. hits every element of $B$), such that $f$ restricted $C$ is not surjective?

Comment: F(0)=F(1)=0=1? Does this work?

Comment: Do you know the answers to the rest

Comment: For (b), with the sets above, you can use $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Make sure to check that this function has the properties that you're looking for.

Comment: If you take any sets $A,B,C$ with $C \subset A$, and any injective function $f:A \rightarrow B$, then it should restrict to an injective function on $C$. This means that any example works for (c), and that no example exists for (d).

Comment: What do you mean any examples work for c.?

Comment: Literally choose any sets $A,B,C$ with $C \subset A$ and $f: A \rightarrow B$ any injective function. Then $f$ will restrict to an injective function on $C$.

Comment: So A=(0,1), B=(1), C=(0) and f(0)=f(1)=0? Does this work

Comment: Injective means $f(x)=f(y)$ only if $x=y$. So that function doesn't work, and in general there won't be any injective functions from $A$ to $B$ if $A$ has more elements than $B$. Try $A=B=\{0,1\}$, and $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=1$.